# Comparing two CSV files in R with some conditions

Tags: r, csv

I have two csv files:

File 1:

```
Year,Month,Day,Stn1,Stn2,Stn3
1979,01,01,10,0,5
1979,01,02,10,1,5,
1979,01,03,0,0,0
1979,01,04,5,10,30
1979,01,05,0,1,3
```

File 2:

```
Year,Month,Day
1979,01,02
1979,01,04
1979,01,05
```

File 1 contains daily data from 1979 to 2000, while File 2 contains random dates (non continuous).

What I want:

[1] Get the common dates between File 1 and File 2 if ANY of the station columns (Stn1 to 3) have values greater than or equal to 20. Then, save the output to a file.

In the above example, the output file should contain the following date:

```
Year,Month,Day,Stn1,Stn2,Stn3
1979,01,04,5,10,30
```

Since Stn 3, has a value of 30.

What I have so far:

I can get the common dates even by using a simple bash command. Unfortunately, I don't know how to filter the common dates satisfying the condition.I was wondering how to do this in R.

I'll appreciate any help on this matter.

--
Lyndz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
dataset <- data.frame(Year = c("1979","1979","1979","1979","1979"),
                      Month = c("01","01","01","01","01"),
                      Day = c("01","02","03","04","05"),
                      Stn1 = c(10,10,0,5,0),
                      Stn2 = c(0,1,0,10,1),
                      Stn3 = c(5,5,0,30,3),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dataset <- dataset %>% mutate(date = paste0(Year,Month,Day))   
filterdata <- data.frame(Year = c("1979","1979","1979"),
                         Month = c("01","01","01"),
                         Day = c("02","04","05"),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
filterdata <- filterdata %>% mutate(date = paste0(Year,Month,Day))

dataset %>% semi_join(filterdata, by = 'date') %>% filter(Stn1 >= 20 | Stn2 >= 20 | Stn3 >=20) %>% select(-date)
```

You can filter your data by `or` condition.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this in R. Using Base R, we can `merge()` the two files, using the `[` form of the extract operator to include only rows from `df1` where `Stn3 >= 20`.

```
 textFile1 <- "Year,Month,Day,Stn1,Stn2,Stn3
 1979, 01, 01, 10, 0, 5
 1979, 01, 02, 10, 1, 5
 1979, 01, 03, 0, 0, 0
 1979, 01, 04, 5,10,30
 1979, 01, 05, 0,1,3"

textFile2 <- "Year,Month,Day
1979,01,02
1979,01,04
1979,01,05"

df1 <- read.csv(text = textFile1,header = TRUE)
df2 <- read.csv(text = textFile2,header = TRUE)

merge(x = df1[df1$Stn3 >=20,],y = df2, by = c("Year","Month","Day"))
```

...and the output:

```
> merge(x = df1[df1$Stn3 >=20,],y = df2, by = c("Year","Month","Day"))
  Year Month Day Stn1 Stn2 Stn3
1 1979     1   4    5   10   30
>
```

By slightly editing the code, we can check for any value in `Stn1` to `Stn3` at or above 20.

```
merge(x = df1[rowSums((df1[4:6] >=20))>0,],y = df2, by = c("Year","Month","Day"))
```

The key change is `rowSums((df1[4:6] >=20))>0` in the row dimension of the extract operator for `df1`. If we evaluate this step by step, first `df1[4:6] > 20` is evaluated, and returns a matrix of logical values.

```
> df1[4:6] >=20
      Stn1  Stn2  Stn3
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Next, we use `rowSums()` to result in a vector that has one element per row in `df1`, and use this to subset `df1` before merging with `df2`.

```
> rowSums((df1[4:6] >=20))
[1] 0 0 0 1 0
>
```

Since only 1 observation has a value > 20 for `Stn1` to `Stn3`, we obtain the same results as illustrated above

When we alter the data to set the value of one of the variables > 20 and merge, the `merge()` function returns 2 rows.

```
# now update data to add another column > 20
df1[2,5] <- 50
merge(x = df1[rowSums((df1[4:6] >=20))>0,],y = df2, by = c("Year","Month","Day"))
```

...and the output:

```
> merge(x = df1[rowSums((df1[4:6] >=20))>0,],y = df2, by = c("Year","Month","Day"))
  Year Month Day Stn1 Stn2 Stn3
1 1979     1   2   10   50    5
2 1979     1   4    5   10   30
>
```

Comment: @Len...this checks only column 3. It should detect if "any" column has a value larger than 20

Comment: Hello @Len Greski, thanks for your code, I didn't know how to read those datasets and I had to type them again as data frames! As simple as `read.csv`

Comment: @Lyndz - you're welcome. There is almost always more than one way to do something in R. Sometimes a `tidyverse` solution is the simplest solution, but often Base R requires a lot less code than the `tidyverse`. The Base R [extract operator](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/rprog-extractOperator.md) is a very powerful feature of the language. As you become more familiar with it, many operations such as subsetting data are very straightforward.

Comment: @alexismenanieves - you're welcome. Older versions of R used to require a `textConnection()` object to read an R object as a data file. At some point they incorporated this into read.* functions as the `text = ` argument. It eases the conversion of manually input data from StackOverflow questions into reproducible examples.